# Should an app edit the global machine.config?

Tags: .net

An app we use edits the `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` file on first launch. The data it adds is this:

```
<appSettings file="">
  <clear />
  <add key="<app-specific token>" value="<path to a file>" />
</appSettings>
```

This seems like a bad idea. Is this a legit thing to do? Or did the app developer find the wrong thing to swing his hammer at?

And a follow-up question. This makes the app impossible to run as a non-admin user. Is there something we can do to fix this behavior?

Comment: in my opinion only if all apps running on the machine have a benefit of the change

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that all settings there are machine wide. So, typical applications that should modify `machine.config` are,

1. Database driver installers, as the default settings might affect all apps.
2. Optimization tools, as they might tune some settings affecting all apps.
3. Other possible cases (too broad to describe).

Back to your case. What kind of configuration do you want to add to `machine.config` in `appSettings`? Do you really need to do that for all apps on the machine? If not, move the settings to your `web.config` and then no administrator permissions are required,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my app. It's supplied by a vendor. There is no good reason that I am aware of for these settings to be global. And it's the only reason the app requires admin rights (because it opens the file read/write no matter what). On Windows 7 we could work around this by changing the permissions on the file/folder, but Windows 10 seems to aggressively protect this folder and permissions don't stick.

Comment: I can only assume the vendor products would install multiple components on your machine, and then the addition to `machine.config` is used cross them as shared configuration. If so, that's a ridiculous move, as there are clearly other options for them. Very likely your only option is to give this installer administrator permissions to run. Changing file permissions on such critical ones should be avoided in most cases, as the default ACLs are hardened and your change opens a hole.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good file to be protective about, but this specific change seems fine. If you have access to change the code, you could remove this and get that config from a less precious file instead. 
There's a chance this code runs 'without knowing where it lives' and needs some sort of central config, but that seems farfetched.